# HTML - image won't center horizontally on page

Tags: html, css

I have an image as a navigation bar that I wanted centered on the page. It has a fixed position which may be making it so it can't be centered.

HTML & CSS:

```css
.navbar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="Images/NavBar.png" alt="" class="navbar" usemap="#navbar-map" />
```

I have tried center tags, `text-align: center`, and `left: auto; right: auto`. None work. What's going wrong?

Comment: Try `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Comment: Do you want to keep it position:fixed?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be `position: fixed` so it can scroll with the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set

```
.navbar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/44/cd/cb/44cdcb484a8febd81c1784cb11a96c7b.jpg" alt="" class="navbar" usemap="#navbar-map" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this with position fixed.

```
left:50%;
top:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the image inside a container, adding the class directly on the image tag is not a very good idea for future stuff.

```css
.navbar {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" class="navbar" usemap="#navbar-map" />
</div>
```

Or use the transformation

```css
.navbar {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" class="navbar" usemap="#navbar-map" />
```